# check the site name hosted on IIS using code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

My site name is "Flows" on IIS if i search with the name "FLOWS" its not working so is it possible that i can search it without case sensitive.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
            {
                var iisManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("ServerName");
                Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = iisManager.Sites.Where(q => q.Name.("Flows")).FirstOrDefault();
                if (site.State == site.Start())
                {
                    site.Stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    site.Start();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `q => q.Name.("Flows")` not sure what syntax is this. Did you observe what you are getting in `iisManager.Sites`?

Comment: Does that compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of [CurrentCultureIgnoreCase or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase or OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx), whichever suits your needs, for example:

```
q => q.Name.Equals("FLOWS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Case insensitivity can be enabled for string comparisons by setting the case rules using a [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) enum value.

Passing any of `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, or `OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the comparison will result in case insensitive comparison. e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var iisManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("ServerName");

            Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = iisManager.Sites.Where(
                q => q.Name.Equals("FLOWS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            )

            if (site.State == site.Start())
            {
                site.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                site.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add some explanation about what you changed in the code and why, it is difficult to spot in the middle of the code